# Determine the set of all complex numbers satisfying the relation $|z|<4$, here $z$ is a complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, domain-theory

Please, solve this above question. Please, tell me how to find domain of a function in terms of complex numbers. I can find domain in terms of real no, but facing issue with complex ones.

If I consider $z=a+bi$, $a,b \in \mathbb R$. then I can get $a^2+b^2<16$. so the real numbers should the interior points of the circle $a^2+b^2=16$. But, what about complex ?

Comment: It's identical. The complex numbers are best understood by their polar form and are intimately tied to circles.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  Any complex $z$ can be represented as $a+bi$ with $a,b$ real.  If you are doing a problem in the complex domain and don't have any other idea, that is a good one to try.  Here it worked well.  $|z|$ is the magnitude of $z$, the distance from the origin, so the answer should be a circle.

Comment: If $z=a+bi$ the you might write $\bar z= a-bi$, and you would then have $z \bar{z} = a^2+b^2$ so $|z| \lt 4$ is equivalent to $z \bar{z} < 16$

Comment: Thanks all. Can I write the domain set as {z:z=a+bi,z belongs to C, a,b belongs to R, a^2+b^2<16} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you showed is the solution. You can identify each complex number $z = a + bi$ with a point $(a, b)$ in the plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. This means that $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ are isomorphic.

The complex modulus (absolute value) is defined to be

$$|z| := \sqrt{Re(z)^{2} + Im(z)^{2}} = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}},$$

where $Re(z) := a$ and $Im(z) := b$ are the real and imaginary parts of $z = a + bi$, respectively.

Thus, when you are asking $|z| < 4$, you are asking for $|z| = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}} < 4$.

You can see a visualization of the complex number in the complex plane here:

[complex number geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#/media/File:Complex_conjugate_picture.svg)

Comment: Thanks. But, can you please say me the domain set ? Can I write the domain set as {z:z belongs to C, z=a+bi, a,b belongs to R, a^2+b^2<16} ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "domain". Usually by domain we mean the set of a mapping/function for which the function/map is defined and makes sense. I assume you mean the solution set. Then, you can write it out as { $ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 4$ } = { z = a + bi \in \mathbb{C} : a, b \in \mathbb{R} a^{2} + b^{2} < 16 }$. There are multiple ways of writing the solution set in set notation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping. 

Answer (score 0):

The points z such that $|z|<4$ are all the points that lie within the disk of radius 4 centered at 0. Let $z=a+ib$, $|z|<4$ implies $a^2+b^2<16$.

Comment: Can you please write it in a set notation ?

Comment: $\{$ $z\in \mathbb{C}$ $:$ $|z|<4$ $\}$